# How to load JPA context and all after fetching JSON from cache and mapping it to JPA entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, redis

I have JPA Entity class as such:

```
class A extends BaseEntity{
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
private B b;

@Column(name = "is_checked")
private Boolean isChecked;    
}

class B{
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "A", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<A> aList;
}
```

Now my function to cache the object is as follows: (the function convert the JPA entity object to JSON string and cache it).

```
public void cacheObject(String suffix, A object) {
    try{
        ...

        redisTemplate
            .opsForValue()
            .set(
                key,
                Jackson.toJsonString(object)
            );

        ...
    }catch(Exception exception){
        ...
    }
}
```

The retrieval function is as follows: (It retrieves the JSON string and map it to the entity class object)

```
public A getById(Integer id) {
    try{
        String aString = this.getObjectFromCache(id.toString());

        if(Utilities.isNull(aString) || aString.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

        return objectMapper.readValue(
            aString,
            A.class
        );
    }catch(Exception exception){
        log.warn("Exception occurred while converting JSON string to A(id:{})", id);
        log.warn("Exception: {}", exception.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to do this a.getB().getAList() [after fetching from cache] it results in error of null pointer exception, as aList of entity B is not being cached as I am using @JsonIgnore on it. If I weren't using @JsonIgnore then there would have been another error of infinite recursion(A->B>A->B->so on) at JSON serialization while caching.
I don't want to cache aList either I want to fetch it from database, but I am unable to do so because of null pointer exception as it is null upon caching, also I tried to just save ids in AList so that if I do a.getB().getAList() then it fetches AList from db using JPA Persistence/context/whatever as ids are now there but it didn't work either.
Any suggestions how to do that? any suggestion on how should I be caching? keep in mind I have a lot of referencing entities.